# NodeJs: Never emits "end" when reading a TCP Socket

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am pretty new to Node.Js and I'm using tcp sockets to communicate with a client. Since the received data is fragmented I noticed that it prints "ondata" to the console more than once. I need to be able to read all the data and concatenate it in order to implement the other functions.  I read the following http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/12/20/streams2/ and thought I can use `socket.on('end',...)` for this purpose. But it never prints "end" to the console.

Here is my code:

```
Client.prototype.send = function send(req, cb) {
    var self = this;

    var buffer = protocol.encodeRequest(req);
    var header = new Buffer(16);
    var packet = Buffer.concat([ header, buffer ], 16 + buffer.length);

    function cleanup() {
       self.socket.removeListener('data', ondata);
       self.socket.removeListener('error', onerror);
    }

    var body = '';

    function ondata() {
    var chunk = this.read() || '';
       body += chunk;
       console.log('ondata');
    }

    self.socket.on('readable', ondata);

    self.socket.on('end', function() {
        console.log('end');
    });

   function onerror(err) {
      cleanup();
      cb(err);
   }

   self.socket.on('error', onerror);
   self.socket.write(packet);
};
```

Comment: Socket doesn't know when the the data ended. Socket just waiting to read data, when the data is received/available. You must end reading from socket manually, when you know that all data that you need already received. For example, when you read data from an URL, you get content length header - so you know that you need stop reading from socket when you received data with that length defined in header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end event will handle the FIN package of the TCP protocol (in other words: will handle the close package)

**Event: 'end'#**

> Emitted when the other end of the socket sends a FIN packet.
>   By default (allowHalfOpen == false) the socket will destroy its file descriptor once it has written out its pending write queue. However, by setting allowHalfOpen == true the socket will not automatically end() its side allowing the user to write arbitrary amounts of data, with the caveat that the user is required to end() their side now.

About FIN package: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination

**The solution**

I understand your problem, the network communication have some data transfer gaps and it split your message in some packages. You just want read your fully content.

For solve this problem i will recommend you create a **protocol**. Just send a number with the size of your message before and while the size of your concatenated message was less than total of your message size, keep concatenating :)

I have created a lib yesterday to simplify that issue:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-easysocket

I hope it helps :)